# How is a UIButton's image set programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

How does one set the image of a UIButton from within the code?

I try the following but it just leaves the button as a white square.

```
[A1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"m1.10001.png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: How did you allocated/initialized your A1 button? are you sure m1.10001.png exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image construction seems a bit overly complicated, but it should work. Don't forget to use the correct button type (custom):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"m1.10001.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

With newer SDKs you can omit the *.png*. Make sure that the image actually exists (you can store it in a temporary variable and check for `nil`, for example).

And of course make sure that the button exists (or is bound), i.e. non-nil, when setting the image.